# Simulator Failed to Install Application

Tags: xcode, ios, sdk, ios-simulator

I've been working on my app over the past few days and I've always been able to simulate it. Today, I compiled and ran, got no errors or warnings, but on the bottom of XCode there is a message saying

```
> Error From Debugger: Failed to launch
> simulated application: iOS Simulator
> failed to install application
```

This is the Internal error window that pops up after trying to "build and go" once again,

> > File:   /SourceCache/IndigoDebuggingPlugin/IndigoDebuggingPlugin-44/iPhoneSimulatorDevice/XCiPhoneSimulatorDevice.m
> >     Line:   341
> >     Object: 
> >     Method: _launchSimulatedExecutable:
>
> Assertion failed: nil ==
>   _currentSimulatorSession

I looked for help around the internet and I've tried deleting my build folder manually, cleaning and building, and I've just recently completely reinstalled XCode and the whole SDK.

Also when quitting XCode with this project open, it gives me this in an error message:

> Failed to close project
>
> Reason: ASSERTION FAILURE in
>   /SourceCache/iPhoneSimulatorRemoteClient/iPhoneSimulatorRemoteClient-18/Source/DTiPhoneSimulatorSession.m:147
>   Details:  requestEndWithTimeout:
>   called on failed session. Object:
>   
>   Method:   -requestEndWithTimeout:
>   Thread:   {name =
>   (null), num = 1} Backtrace:   0 
>   0x00043888 -[DTAssertionHandler
>   handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:messageFormat:arguments:]
>   (in DevToolsFoundation)   1 
>   0x00043518 _DTAssertionFailureHandler
>   (in DevToolsFoundation)   2 
>   0x1e06f807 -[DTiPhoneSimulatorSession
>   requestEndWithTimeout:] (in
>   iPhoneSimulatorRemoteClient)   3 
>   0x1d8a5ca9   4  0x00826b95
>   -[PBXDebugSessionModule stopLaunchSession] (in
>   DevToolsInterface)   5  0x008243c8
>   -[PBXDebugSessionModule closeModule] (in DevToolsInterface)   6  0x9973017d
>   -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] (in CoreFoundation)   7  0x0077f6ea
>   -[PBXModule closeModule] (in DevToolsInterface)   8  0x9973017d
>   -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] (in CoreFoundation)   9  0x0077f6ea
>   -[PBXModule closeModule] (in DevToolsInterface)  10  0x9973017d
>   -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] (in CoreFoundation)  11  0x0099a188
>   -[XCPerspectivesSpecification closeAllModules] (in
>   DevToolsInterface)  12  0x9973017d
>   -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] (in CoreFoundation)  13  0x0076468e
>   -[PBXProjectDocument mainModuleShouldClose:] (in
>   DevToolsInterface)  14  0x00998bf6
>   -[XCPerspectiveModule windowShouldClose:] (in
>   DevToolsInterface)  15  0x000099a1  16
>   0x00007297  17  0x95b8d522
>   -[NSApplication _docController:shouldTerminate:] (in AppKit)  18  0x95b8d048
>   -[NSDocumentController(NSInternal) _continueTerminationHavingClosedAllDocuments:context:]
>   (in AppKit)  19  0x95b8ce26
>   -[NSDocumentController(NSInternal) _shouldTerminateWithDelegate:shouldTerminateSelector:]
>   (in AppKit)  20  0x95b8c6ff
>   -[NSApplication _shouldTerminate] (in AppKit)  21  0x95b8c271
>   -[NSApplication te

I have no idea what to do next, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: XCode Version: 3.2.5
Component versions
Xcode IDE: 1760.0
Xcode Core: 1763.0
ToolSupport: 1758.0

Comment: Does the Simulator start, try deleting the old app-version. is the simulator accessed by another xcode app -> restart simulator can you start the simulator with another x-code project?

Comment: I fixed it by creating a new project and importing (copy+paste) all my code... tedious and time consuming, but it worked

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS Simulator failed to install the application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12932750/ios-simulator-failed-to-install-the-application)

Answer (score 4):

I was encountering this when trying to test my app in the simulator.  Xcode 5, app is for iOS 5.1 up through current iOS 7.0.2 -- Xcode could build and run on the iOS 7 simulator, but would fail to install the app on the iOS 6.1 simulator.  My steps to fix this were

1. Search stackoverflow and read all the comments on this question;
2. Have the iOS Simulator show the system log and watch the log when Xcode tried to build and run on the iOS 6.1 simulator;
3. Notice this important message in the log: `installd[1106]: 0xb0115000 delta_copy: Problem copying package delta`
4. Go to iOS Simulator and delete the iOS 7 version of the app from the "device" (long press on app icon followed by clicking on the (X) removal tab),
5. Build and run successfully with the simulator.

Answer (score 2):

In the simulator application choose ios simulator menu then choose reset Content and settings. This should do.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and after a couple of hours I looked at the Info.plist file as plain text. For some reason, the CFBundleIdentifier value was changed, having the text of some code signing error appended to it. I removed that and everything went back to normal. I hope this will help someone.

Comment: i have removed the value for CFBundleIdentifier, so it was unable to launch

Answer (score 0):

I had this happen before.

Turned out that my target was copying the main info.plist file into the bundle resources.  When I unchecked the info.plist, everything worked fine.

That said, I think there are many things that will cause this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and turned out that @Michael was right.

I recently recreated my Xcode project (Now I'm using Xcode 5.1) and added Info.plist and localized resources (like en.proj) to the 'Resources' group, and that was the problem.

I followed other instructions like resetting Simulator contents and settings, setting shot BundleId, removing apps but the problem happened again and again. I had to delete my app every time I run the app and it was very annoying.

Just removing those files from 'Resources' solved the problem.