# Xcode Error Message: "could not inspect application package"

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, device

I'm trying to run my app on the device but I'm getting the following error message "Could not inspect application package",
the app was successfully running on the device but then it stopped, it still builds successfully.
Other apps are running fine.

This was the error from the console.

> Dec  1 14:08:13 Marafeti kernel[0] : lockbot[567] Builtin profile: gputoolsd (sandbox)
>   Dec  1 14:08:28 Marafeti installd[31] : 0x2ff7c000 handle_install: Install of "/var/mobile/Media/PublicStaging/demoMus.app" requested by mobile_installation_proxy
>   Dec  1 14:08:28 Marafeti installd[31] : 0x2ff7c000 peruse_package: App info dict loaded from "/var/tmp/install_staging.44DhXc/demoMus.app" did not have bundle identifier
>   Dec  1 14:08:28 Marafeti installd[31] : 0x2ff7c000 stage_package: Could not peruse package at /var/tmp/install_staging.44DhXc/demoMus.app
>   Dec  1 14:08:28 Marafeti installd[31] : 0x2ff7c000 MobileInstallationInstall_Server: Could not stage the package
>   Dec  1 14:08:28 Marafeti mobile_installation_proxy[572] : 0x39dbeb88 MobileInstallationInstall: failed with -1
>   Dec  1 14:08:28 Marafeti mobile_installation_proxy[572] : handle_install: Installation failed
>   Dec  1 14:08:29 Marafeti installd[31] : 0x2ff7c000 handle_install: API failed
>   Dec  1 14:11:50 Marafeti dataaccessd[83] : 0x1dd6c3b0|DA|Note |AccountID: E1B4940D-E02C-4ECF-B6AC-7B0DB8BAAA52 ("iCloud") (Legacy)
>       Stats DAStatusReport 0x1e8e9d80: {
>           DASRAccountType = IMAPNotes;
>           DASRPersistentUUID = "E1B4940D-E02C-4ECF-B6AC-7B0DB8BAAA52";
>           DASRTimeSpan = "37.06999397277832";
>       }
>       =======

```
AccountID: ABEE9E0F-D30B-488C-AE35-0A67FFC9D0A8 ("Gmail") (Legacy)
Stats DAStatusReport 0x1ddc6af0: {
    DASRAccountType = IMAPNotes;
    DASRPersistentUUID = "ABEE9E0F-D30B-488C-AE35-0A67FFC9D0A8";
    DASRTimeSpan = "36.95116698741913";
}
=======

AccountID: 00D54212-0B42-4D2E-A7CF-517815381FCC ("iCloud") (Legacy)
Stats DAStatusReport 0x1e8e5e30: {
    DASRAccountType = CalDAV;
    DASRFailedNetworkRequests = 3;
    DASRPersistentUUID = "00D54212-0B42-4D2E-A7CF-517815381FCC";
    DASRSuccessfulRequests = 1;
    DASRTimeInNetworking = "0.1138659119606018";
    DASRTimeSpan = "36.83354198932648";
}
DATaskManager <DACoreDAVTaskManager: 0x1e889060> state:Nominal
Active exclusive task: (null)
Queued exclusive tasks: (null)
Independent tasks: (null)
Held independent tasks: (null)
Modal-held independent tasks: (null)
Active queued task: (null)
Queued tasks: (null)
Active modal task: (null)
Queued modal tasks: (null)

Associated with account: <MobileCalDAVMobileMeChildDaemonAccount: 0x1ddc7740>: accountID 00D54212-0B42-4D2E-A7CF-517815381FCC persistentUUID 00D54212-0B42-4D2E-A7CF-517815381FCC
=======

AccountID: 939CC513-0027-4F6E-821B-CC14022CA49A ("Oxinai") (Legacy)
Stats DAStatusReport 0x1e8ece00: {
    DASRAccountType = CalDAV;
    DASRFailedNetworkRequests = 3;
    DASRPersistentUUID = "939CC513-0027-4F6E-821B-CC14022CA49A";
    DASRSuccessfulRequests = 1;
    DASRTimeInNetworking = "0.06468302011489868";
    DASRTimeSpan = "36.41551601886749";
}
DATaskManager <DACoreDAVTaskManager: 0x1ddfb950> state:Nominal
Active exclusive task: (null)
Queued exclusive tasks: (null)
Independent tasks: (null)
Held independent tasks: (null)
Modal-held independent tasks: (null)
Active queued task: (null)
Queued tasks: (null)
Active modal task: (null)
Queued modal tasks: (null)

Associated with account: <MobileCalDAVChildDaemonAccount: 0x1e8e41f0>: accountID 939CC513-0027-4F6E-821B-CC14022CA49A persistentUUID 939CC513-0027-4F6E-821B-CC14022CA49A
=======

AccountID: C82E01E9-8299-49F2-8501-B0C31E05C8FC ("Gmail") (Legacy)
Stats DAStatusReport 0x1e8ef610: {
    DASRAccountType = CalDAV;
    DASRFailedNetworkRequests = 3;
    DASRPersistentUUID = "C82E01E9-8299-49F2-8501-B0C31E05C8FC";
    DASRSuccessfulRequests = 1;
    DASRTimeInNetworking = "0.04899799823760986";
    DASRTimeSpan = "36.41232699155807";
}
DATaskManager <DACoreDAVTaskManager: 0x1dd7b060> state:Nominal
Active exclusive task: (null)
Queued exclusive tasks: (null)
Independent tasks: (null)
Held independent tasks: (null)
Modal-held independent tasks: (null)
Active queued task: (null)
Queued tasks: (null)
Active modal task: (null)
Queued modal tasks: (null)

Associated with account: <MobileCalDAVChildDaemonAccount: 0x1e8eea60>: accountID C82E01E9-8299-49F2-8501-B0C31E05C8FC persistentUUID C82E01E9-8299-49F2-8501-B0C31E05C8FC
=======

AccountID: 915C5A43-FE6D-4EEE-A157-A7D26671DDAA ("iCloud") (Legacy)
Stats DAStatusReport 0x1ddda4a0: {
    DASRAccountType = CardDAV;
    DASRPersistentUUID = "915C5A43-FE6D-4EEE-A157-A7D26671DDAA";
    DASRTimeSpan = "36.39721202850342";
}
DATaskManager <DACoreDAVTaskManager: 0x1e83be40> state:Nominal
Active exclusive task: (null)
Queued exclusive tasks: (null)
Independent tasks: (null)
Held independent tasks: (null)
Modal-held independent tasks: (null)
Active queued task: (null)
Queued tasks: (null)
Active modal task: (null)
Queued modal tasks: (null)

Associated with account: <CardDAVMobileMeChildDaemonAccount: 0x1ddda0e0>: accountID 915C5A43-FE6D-4EEE-A157-A7D26671DDAA persistentUUID 915C5A43-FE6D-4EEE-A157-A7D26671DDAA
=======

AccountID: 2F8D6492-EB6D-4C65-BB6D-29DB9B9D5FDD ("iCloud") (Legacy)
Stats DAStatusReport 0x1dddcb00: {
    DASRAccountType = BookmarkDAV;
    DASRPersistentUUID = "2F8D6492-EB6D-4C65-BB6D-29DB9B9D5FDD";
    DASRTimeSpan = "36.25405502319336";
}
DATaskManager <DACoreDAVTaskManager: 0x1ddcf400> state:Nominal
Active exclusive task: (null)
Queued exclusive tasks: (null)
Independent tasks: (null)
Held independent tasks: (null)
Modal-held independent tasks: (null)
Active queued task: (null)
Queued tasks: (
)
Active modal task: (null)
Queued modal tasks: (null)

Associated with account: <BookmarkDAVMobileMeChildDaemonAccount: 0x1e8f1670>: accountID 2F8D6492-EB6D-4C65-BB6D-29DB9B9D5FDD persistentUUID 2F8D6492-EB6D-4C65-BB6D-29DB9B9D5FDD
=======

AccountID: A7FA469A-9A67-4C93-8FF7-D60BC81AB75C ("Facebook") (Accountsd)
Stats DAStatusReport 0x1e8a8d40: {
    DASRDisplayName = Facebook;
    DASRPersistentUUID = "A7FA469A-9A67-4C93-8FF7-D60BC81AB75C";
    DASRTimeSpan = "36.18959897756577";
}
No Task Manager initted yet=======

AccountID: 34DBB43F-29EB-4B7A-B8EC-6DBAD3CE87BE ("Facebook") (Accountsd)
Stats DAStatusReport 0x1ddc1710: {
    DASRDisplayName = Facebook;
    DASRPersistentUUID = "34DBB43F-29EB-4B7A-B8EC-6DBAD3CE87BE";
    DASRTimeSpan = "36.06168901920319";
}
No Task Manager initted yet=======

_contactsLockHolder (null)
_contactsWaiters (
)
_waiterIDsExpectingContactsLock {(
)}
_eventsLockHolder (null)
_eventsWaiters (
)
_waiterIDsExpectingEventsLock {(
)}
_notesLockHolder (null)
_notesWaiters (
)
_waiterIDsExpectingNotesLock {(
)}
_bookmarksLockHolder (null)
_bookmarksWaiters (
)
_waiterIDsExpectingBookmarksLock {(
)}
Shared DAPowerAssertionManager object <DADaemonPowerAssertionManager: 0x1dd637c0>:
Contexts asserting power: <NSCountedSet: 0x1ddf9fd0> ()
Contexts held aside: <NSCountedSet: 0x1ddf68f0> ()
Active Assertions: {
}

DARefreshManager enabled wrappers:
Topic "com.me.cal" {
    <DARefreshWrapper 0x1ddc14c0 for delegate <MobileCalDAVMobileMeChildDaemonAccount: 0x1ddc7740>: accountID 00D54212-0B42-4D2E-A7CF-517815381FCC persistentUUID 00D54212-0B42-4D2E-A7CF-517815381FCC: Push state 0, style Poll, last registration: (null)>
}
DARefreshManager wrappers:
    <DARefreshWrapper 0x1e889c90 for delegate <MobileCalDAVChildDaemonAccount: 0x1e8e41f0>: accountID 939CC513-0027-4F6E-821B-CC14022CA49A persistentUUID 939CC513-0027-4F6E-821B-CC14022CA49A: Push state 0, style Poll, last registration: (null)>
    <DARefreshWrapper 0x1dd28170 for delegate <CardDAVAgent: 0x1e8af410>: Push state 0, style Poll, last registration: (null)>
    <DARefreshWrapper 0x1e829ae0 for delegate <BookmarkDAVAgent: 0x1e8af570>: Push state 0, style Poll, last registration: (null)>
    <DARefreshWrapper 0x1ddeeac0 for delegate <MobileCalDAVChildDaemonAccount: 0x1e8eea60>: accountID C82E01E9-8299-49F2-8501-B0C31E05C8FC persistentUUID C82E01E9-8299-49F2-8501-B0C31E05C8FC: Push state 0, style Poll, last registration: (null)>
```

Any advice ?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Not sure...but this looks suspicious: 'demoMus.app" did not have bundle identifier'.  Is there a Bundle Identifier key in your info plist file?

Comment: @PhillipMills Yes there is, I didn't modify it.

Comment: Weird stuff...I'm getting the alert notification 'could not inspect application package' when I add a folder to my app called 'Resources'.  Even if I delete this folder (after I created it) this error persists.  Nothings appearing in my console.  Would love to know why this is as well.

Comment: Try deleting the app on device and installing again?

Comment: Just guessing - remove all your derived folders or at least this one - you can find the location using the organizer. Shut down Xcode and restart it. Remove the app on device then power cycle (reboot) device unconnected to Mac. Now try again.

Answer (score 33):

For me, I copied a folder into Xcode 4.6.2 with the name "Resources". When Xcode asked, I created the folder references for any added folders.

Every time I did this, I would have to goto the Derived applications directory, and delete the build directory for my project to get it working again.

**Solution:** Do not copy a folder by reference into Xcode with the name "Resources". Rename it to something else other than Resources.

Very annoying error.

Comment: I found that I had this issue if the folder even contained the word "Resources"  =(

Answer (score 10):

also try  just doing a Product->Clean

Comment: I had/am having the same problem. Clean did not fix it for me. For me it arose after I added a folder (not using folder references), and then removed it and re-added it using folder references. Restarting Xcode did not help either.

Answer (score 3):

When I replaced the 'Resources' folder on the xcode, by mistake the below option was selected.

> **Create folder references for any added folders**

But the correct option should be,

> **Create groups for any added folders**

Taking care of the above option is important point in saving time ad fixing the above issue. (It is one of the possibilities for getting this error).

Comment: Using "Create groups for any added folders" solved this issue for me.  I also selected "Copy items into destination group's folder".  Those 2 options made all the difference!

Answer (score 2):

the problem is with your bundle name. make sure you assign an bundle id to project, target and info.plist. i had the same issue, it fixed after adding the bundle id :)

Answer (score 2):

I have Created a group named "`Resources`", and then select all resource under Resources folder and select "Create folder references for any added folders"

Answer (score 1):

**Swift Framework**

For me the problem was using a custom Swift framework with files structure similar to the following:

[image]

Taken from:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Concepts/FrameworkAnatomy.html

It turns out that with Swift the right framework structure looks like this:

[image]

After I changed the directory structure to the latter - everything worked as expected

Answer (score 1):

Uncheck the Target Membership in .plist

[image].

Answer (score 0):

I had two issues that solved the problem for me.
First I had configured in XCodes copy files section to copy the ResourceRules.plist and on the other hand there was also added a non-third party ios framework in the copy files section (Storekit in my case). After removing that problem was solved.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue, with an over-the-air Enterprise app, that was working prior to updating to XCode 6.1.

I ran down the usual suspects (Bundle identifier, a file or directory named "resources", Cleaning and Building, etc.). No dice.

Here's what fixed my issue - I renamed my application's .plist file, and copied in a .plist file from a project that was working fine after the XCode update.

Recompiled. Worked.

I didn't do a line by line compare to see what changed... because I had already wasted a day on this. Maybe later. But not today.

Hope this helps someone else NOT spend a wasted afternoon.