# Framework can only work on simulator, but not device

Tags: ios, xcode, build, arm64, dtcoretext

I'm using Xcode Version 7.2 (7C68).

I met a problem after I build DTCoreText project as framework.
DTCoreText.framework works fine on ios simulator, but when i want to test it on device, the following problem showed up:

[image]

I've checked the build settings in the latest [DTCoreText-1.6.17](https://github.com/Cocoanetics/DTCoreText/releases/tag/1.6.17) project:

Target: **DTCoreText (iOS)**

ARCHS: **armv7, arm64**

ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH: **NO**

VALID_ARCHS: **arm64, armv7, armv7s**

I think these settings are OK. Than I "Build for Profiling" by pressing Shift+CMD+i.

> - **Build using simulator:**
>
> I noticed the current device i just used for building is **Simulator
> (iPhone 6 Plus)**. And I find the DTCoreText.framework under the
> **Release-iphonesimulator** folder. by doing this, the DTCoreText.framework only works fine when using iphone simulator, but
> not on real device.
>
> - **Build using device:**
>
> Than I tried to rebuild DTCoreText.framework with the same build
> settings, but using **"Generic iOS Device"** or **"Real Device (eg:
> iPhone 6s)"**. I got the DTCoreText.framework under
> **Release-iphoneos** folder. By doing this, the DTCoreText.framework only works fine when using real device, but not on iphone simulator.

I don't know why it is happening.
How to build DTCoreText.framework for both simulator and real device?

Answer (score 3):

**Problem Solved!!!**

What I need is making a "FAT" Framework for "i386 x86_64 armv7 arm64"!

[How to export "fat" Cocoa Touch Framework (for Simulator and Device)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29634466/how-to-export-fat-cocoa-touch-framework-for-simulator-and-device)

This post helps me a lot!

Just use "**lipo -info**" command to CHECK the ARCHS, for example:

```
admins-MacBook-Pro:~ admin$
admins-MacBook-Pro:~ admin$ lipo -info /Users/admin/Desktop/DT/device/DTCoreText.framework/DTCoreText
Architectures in the fat file: /Users/admin/Desktop/DT/device/DTCoreText.framework/DTCoreText are: armv7 arm64
admins-MacBook-Pro:~ admin$
admins-MacBook-Pro:~ admin$ lipo -info /Users/admin/Desktop/DT/simulator/DTCoreText.framework/DTCoreText
Architectures in the fat file: /Users/admin/Desktop/DT/simulator/DTCoreText.framework/DTCoreText are: i386 x86_64
admins-MacBook-Pro:~ admin$
```

As we can see:

- When build using simulator, xcode generate framework using ARCHS "**i386, x86_64**"
- When build using device, xcode generate framework using ARCHS "**armv7, arm64**"

To Combine the two framework together, use the following command, for example:

```
admins-MacBook-Pro:~ admin$ lipo -create /Users/admin/Desktop/DT/device/DTCoreText.framework/DTCoreText /Users/admin/Desktop/DT/simulator/DTCoreText.framework/DTCoreText -output /Users/admin/Desktop/DTCoreText
```

Now you can find the "DTCoreText" binary file on your desktop. Use lipo cmd to check it again:

```
admins-MacBook-Pro:~ admin$ lipo -info /Users/admin/Desktop/DTCoreText
Architectures in the fat file: /Users/admin/Desktop/DTCoreText are: i386 x86_64 armv7 arm64
```

Yes! the ARCHS are **"i386 x86_64 armv7 arm64"**

Put the "DTCoreText" binary file inside DTCoreText.framework and replace the old one!

Done!

Now we should able to use the framework for both device and simulator!

---

**But**

This is only for the convenience of testing purpose, If you want to submit your app to app store. apple will reject it due to ["iOS frameworks containing simulator slices can't be submitted to the App Store"](http://www.openradar.me/radar?id=6409498411401216).

Please read this post:
[Creating iOS/OSX Frameworks: is it necessary to codesign them before distributing to other developers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30963294/creating-ios-osx-frameworks-is-it-necessary-to-codesign-them-before-distributin)