# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: in Xcode 9.4

Tags: ios, xcode, undefined-symbol

I just created a framework, I created a sample app to test the framework. Everything works fine in Xcode 9 after upgrading the Xcode getting like 
**Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64**. Also I tested the available architectures in terminal by using the command **lipo -info framework** and also using command **file framework**, showing available Architectures are: i386 x86_64 armv7 arm64. I don't know why I am getting this error. Please suggest me if I am doing anything wrong. You can see the error attached screenshot.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: If you open the build window, you'll see which symbols are missing.

Comment: zneak thanks for your reply, you are saying that valid architectures right. If yes, also I tried but didn't worked for me..

Comment: Did you try deleting the derived data? [How can I delete derived data?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40278559/8346251)

Comment: No. I'm talking about the [build log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19014359/how-do-i-view-the-full-build-log-on-xcode5).

Comment: Yes, I did deleting the derived data and removing the references and re-added..But didn't work..

Comment: and also in build logs I didn't find any changes.....

Comment: If I disable **Build Active Archive** getting the above error and When I enable  getting **Undefined symbols for architecture i386**. Its working fine when I archiving the build...

Comment: also I tried to combine the debug and release frameworks using **lipo -create -output "YourFrameworkName" "Debug-iphonesimulator/YourFrameworkName.framework/YourFrameworkName" "Debug-iphoneos/YourFrameworkName.framework/YourFrameworkName"** but no use. If I import debug framework, its working fine in simulator.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this works for others, for me, I merged the debug and release framework using **lipo -create -output "YourFrameworkName" "Debug-iphonesimulator/YourFrameworkName.framework/YourFrameworkName" "Debug-iphoneos/YourFrameworkName.framework/YourFrameworkName"** and also I merged the swiftmodules under modules. [Framework can only work on simulator, but not device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34615853/framework-can-only-work-on-simulator-but-not-device) and
http://www.openradar.me/radar?id=6409498411401216 these two posts helps for me...