# iOS Framework codesign for appStore

Tags: ios, frameworks, app-store-connect

I have created a framework and added it in my other project. Everything is working fine when I generate Adhoc or development build and even app store build is generated successfully. But when I submit my app to iTunesConnect it give me below error:
Despite [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30963294/creating-ios-osx-frameworks-is-it-necessary-to-codesign-them-before-distributin) question says that Framework consumer will re-codesign it. Thanks 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Check if you installed the distribution certificate in keychain access in your mac. Check if the secret key is missing. Make sure it is a valid certificate. Check your provisioning profile in [apple developer portal](https://developer.apple.com/)

Comment: Profiles and certificates are fine. The only issue is how to resolve codesign on Framework.