# How to use a dynamic framework in a framework?

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing, provisioning-profile, codesign

I am building my framework `FooFramework` that uses WebRTC framework. After I used the WebRTC framework(https://github.com/zevarito/PodRTC) in my pod as a dynamic framework. My demo app `FooDemoApp` that uses `FooFramework` crashes as it runs with not- my-own provision profile on a device. The error message is `dyld: Library not loaded... Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find... code signing blocked mmap()`

I think the problem is that Apple seems doens't allow nested framework. The WebRTC will be signed with my `teamIdentifier`, but the `teamIdentifier` is `not set` on my framework. I wonder what's the proper way except for re-code sign WebRTC?

`FooDemoApp` would not crash before I added the PodRTC in `FooFramework` when I run it using not my provision profile on a device.

The relationships between the framework are like this:

`FooFramework`(before built) includes: PodRTC(not code signed) as a Cocoapod

`FooDemoApp`(after built `FooFramework`) includes: my code-signed built `FooFramework`(code signed with `Identifier`:`io.allen.ALSDK`, no team identifier set), which includes code-signed PodRTC(code signed with `Identifier`:`org.webrtc.WebRTC`, team identifier `PodRTCTeam`)

So I have two questions:

1. How to use PodRTC without crashing on a different provision profile?
2. Why my demo app wouldn't crash before while it's running with a different provision profile?

Comment: It says Apple doesn't allow nested frameworks, I wonder how does code sign affect this?
https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet/commit/d7818be0672b8ea39eca01970c4678d0ffc91491

Comment: Or maybe should every user that use the demo app re-code sign the framework?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30963294/creating-ios-osx-frameworks-is-it-necessary-to-codesign-them-before-distributin