# Unable to Upload build from xcode 10.1 adding after InfineaSDK.framework

Tags: ios

[image]I am integrating new SKD InfineaSDK.framework. In my project but is neither archiving nor validating.

> ERROR ITMS-90035: "Invalid Signature. Code object is not signed at
>   all. The file at path
>   [MyApp.app/Frameworks/InfineaSDK.framework/SDKSetup] is not properly
>   signed. Make sure you have signed your application with a distribution
>   certificate, not an ad hoc certificate or a development certificate.
>   Verify that the code signing settings in Xcode are correct at the
>   target level (which override any values at the project level).
>   Additionally, make sure the bundle you are uploading was built using a
>   Release target in Xcode, not a Simulator target. If you are certain
>   your code signing settings are correct, choose "Clean All" in Xcode,
>   delete the "build" directory in the Finder, and rebuild your release
>   target. For more information, please consult
>   https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Conceptual/CodeSigningGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html"

Comment: Are you tried to using AdHoc certificate for uploading build?

Comment: No, I am using iOS Distribution (App Store) and Provisioning Profile Type is also App Store.

Comment: I am Migrating to **InfineaSDK** in my application. Before that this Provisioning Profile was working.

Comment: Are you adding frameworks using Carthage?

Comment: @FaysalAhmed No, I added it manually just dragged

Comment: Would you please check these steps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52438085/5167909

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198662/discussion-between-yogendra-solanki-and-faysal-ahmed).