# Xcode : No code signature found, while running application on real device

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, macos

While running application on device, Its showing me error in popup like : Unable to install "XXXX"
This is working fine while running in simulator. Is it bug of Xcode or am i doing something wrong?. Please help.
Thanks in advance.
Details

### Unable to install "XXXX"
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402620388

No code signature found.
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402620388

```
User Info: {
DVTRadarComponentKey = 261622;
MobileDeviceErrorCode = "(0xE800801C)";
"com.apple.dtdevicekit.stacktrace" = (
0   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x00000001226f593f DTDKCreateNSErrorFromAMDErrorCode + 220
1   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000122734124 __90-[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:]_block_invoke + 155
2   DVTFoundation                       0x000000010724eb33 DVTInvokeWithStrongOwnership + 71
3   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000122733e65 -[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:] + 1440
4   IDEiOSSupportCore                   0x00000001225a4d28 __118-[DVTiOSDevice(DVTiPhoneApplicationInstallation) processAppInstallSet:appUninstallSet:installOptions:completionBlock:]_block_invoke.292 + 3513
5   DVTFoundation                       0x000000010737d29a __DVT_CALLING_CLIENT_BLOCK__ + 7
6   DVTFoundation                       0x000000010737eebc __DVTDispatchAsync_block_invoke + 1191
7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6f92e6c4 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6f92f658 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6f934c44 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 597
10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6f9355d6 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 363
11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6f93ec09 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 596
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff6fb89a3d _pthread_wqthread + 290
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff6fb88b77 start_wqthread + 15
```

);
}

--
System Information
macOS Version 10.15.5 (Build 19F101)
Xcode 12.1 (17222)

Comment: Which device are you building for, iOS device or mac? (Its in the toolbar at the top in Xcode)

Answer (score 0):

I also had that problem with third party library (TFLTensorFlowLite.framework). I change in section "Framework, Libraries, and Embedded Content" from "Do Not Embed" the error disappear. If I change to "Embed & Sign" the problem will show again. I use Xcode 13.4.1

Answer (score -1):

> Is it bug of Xcode or am i doing something wrong?

**It's not a bug.** You just need to set up your app and/or device to enable the device to run your app.

You can run anything on a simulator, but to run your app on a device the code needs to be signed, so you need a certificate and development provisioning profile that includes the UDID of your test device. See [*Run an app on a device*](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev5a825a1ca) in the [Xcode Help](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/devc8c2a6be1) for detailed info about how to set that up. Usually, just having an active developer account and setting Xcode up to handle provisioning automatically should do the trick.

Comment: Hi @Caleb, I am using  development provisioning profile and my device UDID is added there.

Comment: It's happening for me after adding .xcframework, it installs fine without this framework.

Comment: @bojan The answer here might help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30963294

Comment: @Caleb thanks, I will check it out! My project it's a bit more complicated, because it has multiple types of dependencies. The same .xcframework works fine when I use it in smaller project. But it's not the case of having Xcode handling provisioning automatically in my case, I actually used the Apple's documentation about code signing (it's very well written) and I will look into my issue later today.