# Can't install react native app after build succeeded in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I am building an app on top of React Native White Label App sdk. Whenever I run `yarn install {package_name}` and `arch-x86_64 pod install`, a pop up on xcode says "unable to install the app {app_name}"

```
Details

Unable to install "awesomeMsdkProject"
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402653103
--
Could not inspect the application package.
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402653103
--


System Information

macOS Version 11.5.1 (Build 20G80)
Xcode 12.5.1 (18212) (Build 12E507)
Timestamp: 2021-10-25T15:36:56+05:00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you use third-party code that is not signed by you? There are two questions, which may be related to your problem:
[Xcode: Could not inspect the application package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26015194/xcode-could-not-inspect-the-application-package)
and
[“could not inspect application package” Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14630828/could-not-inspect-application-package-xcode/14631281#14631281).