# iOS simulator failed to install the application, common fixes not working

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, xcode5

Today, while trying to fix an issue with outlets within my app, I tried to launch it and received the "iOS simulator failed to install the application" error. There are no issues within the app. The only thing I changed between the time that it worked and that it didn't was to type in the custom class setting. I deleted what I had typed after I noticed it not working. I have tried the reset contents and settings option multiple times, and I have cleared all the "issues" with the app, and it still will not launch. Anyone have any other ideas? (xCode 5 for iOS, BTW)

Comment: Does the app compile?  And you have successfully launched on a simulator in the past?  If so, check what simulator you have installed within Xcode preferences.  You may need to reinstall, especially if the target OS version is significantly different than the one installed

Comment: Also, this post could be a poster for "Why should I use source control?"

Comment: @Jeremyw, yes, it has worked in the past. I have been working on it for ~6 weeks, so I have ran it countless times. Also, when I try to build it, it flashes that transparent gray box that says "build succeeded", shortly before saying "iOS simulator failed to install application".

Comment: You think that's weird!  I got a thing going where the app will launch on the simulator; but not pass the load screen. If you Reset the simulator it works fine.  Next time, same problem. So, you have to reset the simulator every single run!  Heh.

Comment: See this answer, solved it for me:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/16279286/1927253

Answer (score 1):

So try all of the following one by one, until it works

- delete the app from the Simulator (press and hold just like on a real device)
- shut down Xcode, the Simulator, reopen and try again
- clean the app, recompile, try to run again
- from the organizer, remove the Derived Data folder, rebuild and run
- try using a different simulator - that is Retina 3.4, Retina 4, etc
- reset the Simulator

Sigh - if you get here Xcode is hosed, or your project got hosed. Add a comment if all else fails, I'll give you some more thoughts.

EDIT: so still no luck. At this point you almost have to brute force it. Lets assume now that something small but really serious has happened. You need to make 100% sure that the Storyboard file is both named correctly in the file view, in the plist, and the storyboard is in the "copy files to bundle".

Do you have even a zipped old copy? If so you can use it to compare to the latest broken project, or if not then choose any similar project (some iPhone app).

Look at the Scheme to make sure all is correct there - and compare to a working project.

Now go looking at and comparing the PLIST, the project settings, then the Target settings. Look at the Target build settings, and the list of files in the Copy Bundle Resources (where you better see the image assets, the storyboards, etc). Look at everything.

Build the app in say Release mode (you did try both Release and Debug already, right?), go to your derived folder. Compare the broken app to a good one. Are the folder structures the same, are the files you expect to find there, including the binary object, there. Images too. You can go to the folder using Terminal and find out the types of objects in the binary - I think "file fileExecutable" does it but there is some other command too.

Comment: One other option that has worked for me is to delete the app from the simulator, rebuild and run.

Comment: @Magnetoz my mistake - I thought I'd added it!

Comment: @DavidH, I tried all of those except the derived data one, because I do not know how to find it. Is that within Xcode or do I need to find it in the Finder? (I haven't used a mac prior to starting this project) The app is not on the simulator anymore because I reset the simulator, so I can not delete it. If there's anything else you can suggest, I would appreciate it.

Comment: @DavidH, found and deleted the derived data, still not working.

Comment: @user3022503 I assume that other projects are working fine, so you don't believe its Xcode. Did you try the other simulators - even an iPad one?

Comment: @DavidH, yes, I have tried the other simulators. One thing I have noticed is that all the files under the project folder are red, could that have anything to do with it? Also, in the copy files to bundle, the storyboard is red. I don't think it has been red in the past, though I could be wrong.

Comment: Uh, well that's a problem for sure! Did you rename your folder by any chance? What the red means is the files cannot be found. So Xcode thinks they are in a different folder. Open the right pane, click top left button to get "file" mode, click on a file left pane. Xcode will tell you in the right side where it **thinks** that file is. It should then be obvious what the problem is. Really, you should have mentioned this before and saved everyone a lot of typing...

Comment: Sorry for not saying it earlier, I hadn't noticed it yet. I looked and it appears to all be where they think it is. I would upload a picture of it, but I do not have the reputation required for that. One of the files has a symbol over the picture, it looks like the no smoking sign. Also, the file has .dSYM following it, and the file within Xcode does not. The other file that is red, the .xctest file, is exactly where it says and it has the same name.

Comment: My best advice at this point is that you should rename the folder that this project is in, create a new project same name in a folder of the old name, then copy all the old files to the new project file or folder at a time, then add the files to the new project in Xcode after opening the new project. Your project file must have gotten corrupted. I also suggest running Disk Utility and verify your disk to insure no corruption.

Comment: @DavidH, I did all of that. I have the same problem, but now, I am noticing that they are not where they should be. In fact, I believe they do not exist on my computer, nor the folder they should be in. I searched for the names, and nothing came up. The files in question are the .app file and the .xctest file, both under products within Xcode. I really appreciate all of your help up to this point, and if you're out of ideas, I completely understand.

Comment: My last comment is this: if you can create a new project and run it - some silly little one view iOS app - then its how you are configuring this one project. If you cannot even create a new project and run it, and you've tried to delete Xcode and re-install it, then you have bigger problems than I can solve. I don't know if the Guru's at the Apple Store could help, its possible. Find an iOS/Cocoa Meetup group, and go there and ask for help (with your laptop of course). If you can get in the same room with an experienced person (and you only have problems with this one project), would help.

Comment: Alright, I will look into it. I was trying the putting it in a new folder with the same name thing you recommended earlier, and it started screwing up again when I moved the main.m file into the new one, so I have a feeling it may be corrupted. Again, I can't thank you enough for all your help.