# iOS app won't be installed to iOS simulator or real device

Tags: ios, xcode5

My iOS app won't be installed to iOS simulator or real device.
Env: Xcode5, OSX 10.9.

- No problem on compiling.
- I tried to clean my project and delete cache from organiser.
- I tried most of solutions found on the websites.

I got following error message with AppCode console,

> failed installing application, reason: Error
>   Domain=JBDeviceKitErrprDomain Code=-402653103
>   "AMDeviceSecureUpgradeApplication failed with err = -402653103(Could
>   not inspect the application package.)" UserInfo=0x600000678240
>   {NSLocalizedDescription=AMDeviceSecureUpgradeApplication failed with
>   err = -402653103(Could not inspect the application package.)}. Reason:
>   AMDeviceSecureUpgradeApplication failed with err = -402653103(Could
>   not inspect the application package.)

Process finished with exit code 0

Do you have a good solution? Thanks.

Comment: try [similar question 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13659409/xcode-error-message-could-not-inspect-application-package) or [similar question 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14630828/could-not-inspect-application-package-xcode) (_fyi: multiple google hits and in almost all cases, the word `Resources` creeps up...  a likely hint ;)

Comment: Thanks!!! Your comment helped me, and I solved that problem completely!

Comment: great! :) _you might want to post an answer with the steps you took to resolve your problem so it might help others who are facing the similar issue_