# App Installation Failed: Could Not Inspect the application package

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, xcode6

Whenever i try running my app from xcode 6 (using objective-c) onto my iphone 5 ios 8 it gives me this error:

**App Installation Failed: Could Not Inspect the application package**

But when i run the app on my ipad air ios 7.1 and the iphone simulator ios 8 it works and does not give me this error. Does anyone have suggestions on how to fix this problem? I thank anyone who answers in advance.

Comment: Check out this question/answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13659409/xcode-error-message-could-not-inspect-application-package