# App installation failed: Could not inspect the application package - App info dict did not have Bundle Identifier

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6, device, provisioning-profile

A bit of scenario. I have problems installing the app in tester devices through TestFlight, so I started checking whether the problem was in the .ipa file.

Thus I tried installing the .ipa archive in my iDevice from Xcode (I have Xcode 6.1.1 and I did this in Windows > Devices > Select device from the left tab > Click on the + button under the Installed App). But it gives me this alert error:

```
App installation failed
Could not inspect the application package.
```

I tried to install the app again, checking the logs, and I have seen these  messages

```
    <Warning>: LaunchServices: Please include the kCFBundleIdentifierKey in the options dictionary when installing an app.
    ...
    <Error>: 0x100484000 peruse_package: App info dict loaded from "/var/tmp/install_staging.rw1xlZ/NAME_APP.ipa.app" did not have bundle identifier
```

I opened the NAME_APP.ipa archive, and inside the NAME_APP.app package I verified that a info.plist file exists in and that it contains the Bundle Identifier.

I also checked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13659409/xcode-error-message-could-not-inspect-application-package), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26015194/xcode-could-not-inspect-the-application-package) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14630828/could-not-inspect-application-package-xcode/14631281#14631281)

But I have no "resource" folder in my project, no not-latin character in my product name and I also tried to code-sign all 3d party library I used with the same certificate used for the project with no success.

Any other ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Does your project name contain a space in it?

Comment: No, it doesn't. Thanks anyway.