# TitaniumStudio not updating new files

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, titanium

I am building an application using TitaniumStudio (not by my choice), and am having some very strange and annoying behaviors. I can edit text and the different javascript files and that will update how the app looks, but if I replace an image with a new one, a video with a new one, or audio clip with a new one, the images when I run in the simulator, are the same as the old ones. I imagine it is caching the old images somewhere and that is causing this behavior, but I have been searching trying to find where and can not. Does anyone know what could be causing this?

I am building for iOS from Titanium

Titanium SDK 3.0.2.GA

The project is also using Alloy and Coffee

I have also tried deleting the build folder that titanium creates.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: in web development you can force cache reload simply by changing the URI of the resource like image.gif becomes image.gif?version=2 would that work?

Comment: but that would require me to do this every single time there is a small tweak to the image. That is a bit annoying and impractical when I am replacing 150+ files frequently

Comment: perhaps you can do a ?RANDOMVALUE instead?

Comment: a random value is awfully hacky. There has to be some logical solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In such cases i prefer the following. Sometimes I'm - however - required to restart studio (and sometimes even my mac)

1. Quit Studio
2. Remove build folder manually
3. Open iOS Simulator and remove the app
4. Close Simulator
5. Start Studio
6. Project Clean in Studio
7. Run the app again on simulator.

If this doesn't work try to reset the simulator.  Use 'iOS-Simulator' menu right next to the apple icon, there you can reset content and settings.

Comment: After doing this I am getting a new error now. `[ERROR] :  [DEBUG] Session could not be started: Error Domain=DTiPhoneSimulatorErrorDomain Code=1 "iOS Simulator failed to install the application." UserInfo=0x103e03b50 {NSLocalizedDescription=iOS Simulator failed to install the application., DTiPhoneSimulatorUnderlyingErrorCodeKey=-1}`

Comment: nevermind, that was an easy fix, just used this thread here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12932750/ios-simulator-failed-to-install-the-application but I am still getting the same old pictures for some reason.

Comment: did you test this on a device? It might sound stupid but maybe you should remove & import media files again.

Comment: I got it working now. I had to also go and delete all files in the Resources folder from the directory except for `app.js`. Once I did this, it worked fine