# iOS Simulator failed to install the application after installing a new macosx

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I've copied my Xcode.app ( Version 5.1.1 / Ios 7.1 ) from Application folder and then i've installed a new MacOSX 10.9.4
After moving it back to the application folder it run perfectly except the ioS applications.

When i'm trying to run any ioS application on simulator, i built successfully but i got this message and the simulator doesn't run the app

```
iOS Simulator failed to install the application.
```

I've tried the solutions that other people provided here like (Reset content and settings .. delete the folders in Library/Developers/Xcode and Library/ApplicationSupport/ios simulator ) but also it doesn't solve this issue :/

Answer (score 0):

Deleting contents of ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator and re-run the project solved this problem. or you can simply reset content and setting of the simulator.

[iOS Simulator failed to install the application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12932750/ios-simulator-failed-to-install-the-application)

or try this

https://discuss.appium.io/t/ios-simulator-failed-to-install-the-application/81

Comment: He already mention in the question that This solution does not work for him.