# Simulator in use and even restarting XCode doesn't solve it

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

I sometimes get a dialog in Xcode which states "Simulator in use."  Restarting Xcode didn't help.

I have no Simulator Icon in the Taskbar to quit it and I have no running Simulator.

Is there any solution without rebooting?

Comment: Not in my experience.

Answer (score 0):

I know some of these points to not adress your specific issue since you wrote restarting Xcode would not help you but I'll try to provide a full list of possible fixes for people who might stumble upon this one day.

- Is the "Stop" Button in the left corner of Xcode still clickable ? ==> Click It
- Try to reset contents & settings of iOS Simulator
- Clean Build & Clean Project
- Quit iOS Simulator (look at the Activity Monitor if there is still something running)
- Restart Xcode
- Restart Mac

This is all I can think of. For me most of the times I can resolve it by just restarting Xcode. As you wrote this does not work for you so maybe some of the other points of my list will help you.

Normally this happens when you terminate the iOS Simulator but not the debug session itself, which is why most of the times the "Stop" button in the left corner is clickable most of the times...

Comment: Thanks a lot. Where do I reset contents & settings ?

Comment: You can select it via the context menu of the iOS Simulator: See here for further details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12932750/ios-simulator-failed-to-install-the-application.

Comment: Reset contents and settings has nothing to do with this.

Answer (score 0):

This dialog (and the state that triggers it) comes entirely from Xcode and not the simulator itself.  This dialog will present itself if Xcode is already using the simulator from another workspace.  For example, if you have three projects open at the same time and you do a Build&Run (eg: click "play") in one of them, you will get this dialog if you do a Build&Run in one of the other projects.